# Spring Thymeleaf send object from select option

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I have a problem with sending an object with values from inputs fields to controller in add user method. It generates an error ("Bad request") caused by a select box.
Tables connection works well, I can print a list of users and add user window, but adding a user is not working.

Code:

Entity class fragment (further are getters and setters with hibernate annotations)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_emes")
public class UserEmes implements java.io.Serializable {

private long idUser;
private String code;
private String name;
private String surname;
private Permission permission; -> object from another Table called "permissions"
private String login;
private String password;
private boolean isActive;
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_permissions")
    public Permission getPermission() {
        return permission;
    }
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userForm(Model model)  {
        model.addAttribute("user", new UserEmes());
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") UserEmes userEmes)  {
        emesUserService.addUser(userEmes);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/all-users");
    }
```

Html (select box):

```
<div class="form-group input-group has-feedback">
<span class="input-group-addon"> <label>UPRAWNIENIA</label>
</span> 
<div
th:if="${permissionsList != null and not #lists.isEmpty(permissionsList)}">
<select class="form-control" name="permission">
<option th:each="dropDownItem : ${permissionsList}"
    th:value="${dropDownItem.getIdPermission()}"
    th:text="${dropDownItem.toString()}" />
    </select>
</div>
```

Some screenshots:
[List of users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BrFL.png)
[Add user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJgX0.png)

This is how it looks. As you can see a list of Permissions is correctly loaded to select box, and when u fill rest of the fields it shows "Bad request" error on blank screen.

Is in the thymeleaf possibility to do such things?
I am waiting for your answers.

Comment: Can you also include your form tag?

Comment: <form autocomplete="off" action="#" th:action="@{/addUser}"
   th:object="${user}" method="post" data-toggle="validator"> .... </form>

Comment: @Beast then use `th:field` with `*` operator on `select`

Comment: it didn't help..

Comment: And you did ofc check the documentation I linked in my answer

Comment: Yes.. subsections 6.6 and 6.6 but it's not like in my example. I am asking if that is possible: <select th:field="*{permission.getIdPermission()}" class="form-control"><option th:each="permissionItem : ${permissionsList}"th:value="${permissionItem}"th:text="${permissionItem.toString()}" /></select>  Object user with field (Permission permission), and set that permission field with this select box

Comment: You see, maybe you did read it, but you didnt understand what it says. You are not supposed to bind to id but to property of root entity as whole. field is permission, value is permission id(cuz you are iteration over all possible values that are de-facto detached from context).

Comment: Iv pasted an working example of `select` fields im my answer.

Comment: @Beast And section 6.6 is not what you want as it is about dynamic fields. You have static select field, so section 6.5 explains how it should be done.

Answer (score 3):

You should use tymeleaf backbean binding for that not raw ids

```
<select th:object="${user}"  th:field="*{permission} class="form-control" name="permission">
<option th:each="dropDownItem : ${permissionsList}"

    th:value="${dropDownItem.getIdPermission()}"
    th:text="${dropDownItem.toString()}" />
    </select>
```

This way you will isntruct thymeleaf to bind permission property to given select field (and options). Notice `th:object`, `th:field` and `*` operator, this is not a typo, star should be used here insteed of `$`.

Check documentation for Spring-Thymeleaf integration, it is described there
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html and check how to create `select` inputs.

PS: Here is a sample of `select` field from one of projects of mine

```
<div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('city') ? 'has-error' : _}">
            <label class="control-label" for="place-city">City</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="place-city" th:field="*{city}">
                <option value="" selected>----SELECT CITY----</option>
                <option th:each="city : ${allCities}" th:value="${city.id}" th:text="${city.name}"></option>
            </select>
            <span class="help-block" th:each="msg : ${#fields.errors('addressLine')}" th:text="${msg}">Some error message for this field</span>
        </div>
```

Controller side:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add")
@Transactional
public String addPlacePost(@Valid final Place place, BindingResult placeValidation, Model model) {
```

Where root entity is `Place` that have property of `private City city`.

Comment: But can u show me a fragment of your controller for that? I think in post method u are taking only int/long variable, and I want take object User which has Permission in it, but it's not loading it..

Comment: @Beast Bzzzz, again you think wrong. I know exactly what you want to achieve, and this is how it should be done. It works in my case, should work in yours. 
Iv added controller method signature for your knowledge. As you can see, it accepts my domain class `Place` as argument, `BindingResult` and `Model` are optional. What I get after post, is fully initialized `Place` object with attached entities with `Services` `Categories` and `City` (so this is not the only one x-to-one relation in this example that works. Take carefull look on if you are not missusing `*` and `$` operators.

Comment: BTW it would be wise to take a look on actuall POST data that browser is sending. So check that out, and attach formatted POST data to your question, this way we will see what you are actually sending (with EP URL and headers please). It should ease heliping you out.

Answer (score 2):

I just do this.. 
I set the default value of the object to a new instance, then set the value of the option as the id of the object. but of course depending on your usage you may have to use that id to find the object.

Controller:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_emes")
public class UserEmes implements java.io.Serializable {

private long idUser;
private String code;
private String name;
private String surname;
private Permission permission = new Permission();
private String login;
private String password;
private boolean isActive;
 ...
```

Thymeleaf:

```
 <select th:field="${userEmes.permission.id}" >
     <option th:each="perm : ${perms}" th:value="${perm .id}" th:text="${perm.name}"></option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did everything including registering an object formatter. But only the above solution(@Troll173) worked for me. I modified the th:field to * version to maintain consistency inside form tag.

```
<select th:field="*{permission.id}" >
     <option th:each="perm : ${perms}" th:value="${perm .id}" th:text="${perm.name}"></option>
 </select>
```